# How To Access Model Class Variable in Django Admin Change Form Template Before Save

Tags: django, django-admin

Say I have a model in which I have a class variable called `documentation`. I want to access the `documentation` class variable in the given models change form template. How can I do this? After the instance has been saved I can access the class variable in the template with `{{original.documentation}}`.

**Example Model**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    # How do I access this variable in my change form template 
    # before saving the new instace?
    documentation = "The Person model will be used for all staff including researchers, professors, and authors."

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by updating Django view methods in the ModelAdmin class https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#other-methods.

```
def add_extra_context(model, kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("extra_context", {})
        kwargs["extra_context"]["documentation"] = model.__dict__.get('documentation','')


class DocumentableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def add_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
        add_extra_context(self.model, kwargs)
        return super(DocumentableAdmin, self).add_view(*args, **kwargs)

    def changelist_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
        add_extra_context(self.model, kwargs)
        return super(DocumentableAdmin, self).changelist_view(*args, **kwargs)

    def change_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
        add_extra_context(self.model, kwargs)
        return super(DocumentableAdmin, self).change_view(*args, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Person, DocumentableAdmin)
```

Now the documentation class variable defined in the model will be available in the change form admin template accessible using `{{ documentation|safe }}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/) for this. Create a form and refer that in your view like `formname = forms.formname()`. They you can display whole form using `{formname}` tag.

Its better to manipulate your variables in forms.py instead for templates. But you can access your variable in template if you want by defining a `get_context_data(self, **kwargs)` function in your view class like:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(view_name, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['model_field_list'] = Modelname.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["modelname_pk"])
        return context
```

And now you can access your variables using `{model_field_list.fieldname}` tags in templates. Check the documentation on get_context_data function here: [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data)